Saleforce Flow - Possible Permissions Error
I have a screen flow that is failing on the create record element for the Account object (relabled to Party). I'm not familiar with the org but it seems like the fields invovled are from a managed package.
The field is appearing as Account.litify_pm__Last_Name__c but when you click into that field in the flow it dissapears and the field no longer shows up as an option to set within the create records. I checked FLS and I have access to all the fields on the object. Any tips would be appreciated, I'm not familiar witht the org.
I checked FLS for the object and gave myself modify all to the object and edit access to the fields. I was expecting for the fields to show up wihin the flow after that but they did not.
